# How to find the largest value among 15 values ​that correspond to the total sum of 15 rows in Java?

Tags: java

I have a 15x7 matrix, in which I store the number of attendees who have seen the 15 movies in each of the 7 rooms, I need to know which is the most viewed movie and for that I add the total number of attendees for each movie, however, I don't know how to find the largest value among the 15 total sums.
I have the following code. I appreciate if you could help me

```java
private void PeliculaMasVistaButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    Main window = new Main();

    //Add rows to know the total number of attendees per movie
    int sumRows;
    for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
        sumRows = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < 7; j++) {
            sumRows += Main.attendants[i][j];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume your 2D array is already filled with attendance values
You need to create 3 temp variables

```
{
       int room= 0;
       int movie= 0;
       int largestAttendace= Main.attendants[room][movie];
    
        for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < 7; j++) {
                   if (Main.attendants[i][j] > largestAttendace) {
                      largestAttendace = Main.attendants[i][j]
                      room = i; //save row
                      movie = j; // save col
                    }
                    
                }
            }
    
    System.out.println( "The largest attendace is " + largestAttendace  + " room is " + room + " for movie " + movie);
}
```